# Laravel 5.5.* Sessions Storage Host

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem on my laravel App
First
In localhost (Wamp) 
or with

> Php artisan serve

The Middleware Auth work fine but when i send my application on server i can login. I have do some research i have trace the application with Tinker and i get this

> Psy Shell v0.8.17 (PHP 7.2.10 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>
> > > Auth::loginUsingId(1);
> > >       PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/cpanelUser/Laravel/storage/framework/sessions/1dbnGezV1FREcSz8SIg7rH8Ju4eKFhfyAErspPKB): No such file or directory in /home/cpanelUser/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 183
> > >       => App\User {#211
> > >            id: "1",
> > >            role_id: null,
> > >            name: "Assoumou Anghai Yann",
> > >            email: "Mailto@date.com",
> > >            avatar: "users/default.png",
> > >            contact: "78009969",
> > >            user_type: "adminer",
> > >            settings: null,
> > >            created_at: "2018-10-01 03:31:39",
> > >            updated_at: "2018-10-01 03:31:39",
> > >          }

Thanks for your answer...

Comment: Local Filesystem permissions problems?

Comment: Hum, i have 755 for all folder permission on the server.

Comment: Please note that with 755 you can also hit problems when user group is wrong...

Comment: Finally I have resolve my problem, you get the same problem when you hosting your Laravel App is because is Laravel 5.x storage can't add by symlink so you have to put all content off the public folder on the main folder of your Laravel app. For exemple Main folder /Laravel  here /Laravel/public  you move all /Laravel/public to Laravel and you have to Modify Autoloader from Index.php after that you Laravel app can Work Again. I have resolve this problem After 2 Days @Bart